# Mono for Android: Listview scrolling issue with spinners and edit text

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, xamarin.android, spinner

My problem is on two fronts.

**First issue**: Scrolling amnesia

I have a ListView with spinners and edit texts. It acquires it's data from webservice. The problem is when I write up a value on the EditText or select something for the spinners and scroll them out of view. When I come back the fields are empty and the spinners are again in their default selection.

*Attempted solution*
I have tried resolving the issue by setting ScrollingCacheEnabled programmatic and within the AXML file to both true and false just to see if that is an issue. It seems not to have any kind of an effect.

**Second issue**: Focus Loss

When I touch the EditText within this same ListView I get the keyboard to appear but I loose the focus on the field and it needs to get touched again to get focus and it allows me to be written.

*Attempted solution*
I fiddled with setting the fields focusable, Focusavle in toucmode, touchable and whatnot but came out empty handed.

Honestly I am quite new to android and to programming on this level as well but I tried my best on this. I might have just missed something due to lack of knowledge or it's just something somebody with more experience could tackle and solve.
The second issue isn't that bad for now (still after filling out quite a number of fields it does get tiring to set it twice...) but the scrolling issue is a must.

Comment: Can you post some code? I can't be sure from your description but it sounds like you have some code resetting your UI.

Comment: Sure...
[pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/ff8mKQK9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by replacing the listview with LinearLayout and pinning the adapter to it. The "fixed" code is available on pastebin.

**Fixed code:**

http://pastebin.com/vn3SPrFz

Answer (score 1):

I think you problem relates to that you forget to update the items in the `Adapter`s when you alter the `View`s containing them. So you need to wire up the events from the `View`s to update the items.

Why? If you look carefully at your `Adapter` for you `ListView` you populate the `convertView` with the values of `GetItem(position)`. So if that item does not reflect the changes you have made to the `View` you are bound to get the initial values of that item.

So what you need to do is to hook up `SpinnerValue.ItemSelected` and all the other `View`s which can be altered events, so that the items in the `Adapter` get their values updated. Remember to only add event handlers when you first create the `View`. So that is when `convertView` is null.

Also consider changing the lines:

```
if (SpinnerValue.Adapter.Count.Equals(2))
{
    SpinnerValue.SetSelection(1);
}
```

To be based on the items in the Adapter rather than setting it to 1 every time.

You focus problem is based in that `ListView` is not really made for having `View`s inside of it wanting the focus. Try setting the `ListView` `DecendantFocusability` when you instantiate it to `DescendantFocusability.AfterDescendants` like so:

`lstPrevzem.DescendantFocusability = DescendantFocusability.AfterDescendants;`

Comment: The `DecendantFocusability` part worked like a charm. However I'm afraid I have you on a complete loss for the first part. I don't know how to even begin on that if I'm bloody honest :/
Yet still thank you for your help yet again.